# Logs, Risk/Issue Log

Tags: discussion-board, edit-form, edit, version-comments, log

How does one create a Log of various discussion points on SharePoint?  How does another user add comments to a specific point on the Log?  Is there a Template for SharePoint users to upload that is a Log format?

Answer (score 0):

There are no list templates from Microsoft for this purpose. Various products (free or paid) provide this functionality. I prefer creating a custom list and add a column 'Comments' with type 'Multiple lines of text' (set the option 'Append Changes to Existing Text' to 'Yes'). You need to enable versioning for this list otherwise this field will only capture the last comment.